# Pushing Object literal into an array inside another object literal

Tags: javascript

Im trying to push multiple object literal which name 'qs' into an array inside another object literal named 'uinput', my logic here is that every question consist of its own options, the options object reference are array which its length is based on how much the user add same as question. The intended result is that after the initial while loop the `qs.question` is set to **1st question**, and after the nested while loop `qs.options` arrays contain **option_1st_1 and option_1st_2**, and finally push it into the `uninput.all_question` array, and same goes the second iteration. but the actual result is both question and options are the same example snippet:
[image]
and this is the website.
[image]

My javascript code:

```
var all_question_asnwer_container = document.getElementById('create-question-container-id');
const SubmitForm = () =>{
    var userinputs = [];
    const uinput = {
        title : document.getElementById('create-title-textarea-id').value,
        description : document.getElementById('create-description-textarea-id').value,
        all_question : [
        ],
    }

    let qs = {
        question: this.questiondata,
        options : []
    }

    
    var questioncounter = 0
    
    while(questioncounter < all_question_asnwer_container.childElementCount){
        qs.question = all_question_asnwer_container.children[questioncounter].children[0].value;
        var i = 0;
        while(i < document.getElementById(`create-answer-textarea-container-id-${questioncounter}`).childElementCount){
            qs.options.push(document.getElementById(`create-answer-N-container-id-${questioncounter}-${i}`).children[1].value)
            i++;
        }uinput.all_question.push(qs);
        console.log(document.getElementById(`create-answer-textarea-container-id-${questioncounter}`));
        questioncounter++;
        
    }localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(uinput));
}
```

The uses of the template literal like ${questioncounter} are because every time a user add a new question the dom element attribute id increases. And this my html code:

```
<div class = "create-question-container" id = "create-question-container-id">
            <div class = "create-question-textarea-container" id = "create-question-textarea-container-id_0">
                    <textarea class="create-question-textarea" name="textareaquestion" id = "create-question-textarea-id"cols="50" row="1" style="font-size: 20pt;">Untitled Question</textarea>
                  
                  <div class ="create-answer-textarea-container" id = "create-answer-textarea-container-id-0">
                      
                      <div class="create-answer-N-container" id = "create-answer-N-container-id-0-0">
                        <div class = "create-qeuestion-radio-outer-circle" ><div class = "create-qeuestion-radio-innner-circle" ></div></div>
                        <textarea class="create-answer-textarea" name="textareaopt" placeholder="option1" id = "opt0_0" style="font-size: 14pt;"></textarea>
                      </div>

                  </div>
                  
<button class = "create-add-answer-btn"  id = "create-add-answer-btn-id-0"  onclick="increaseopt(id)">Add Option</button>  
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "create-main-container-submit-button">
          <button class = "create-main-submit-btn" onclick="SubmitForm()">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

The while loop and nested while loop does worked, I tested it with console log, in give me the intended result, but i guess there is something wrong with how i use object literal.

Comment: is this better, the problem is that instead of storing the question with the respective options, both of them store the same question and all the options. Sorry for the nt expressing it very well

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I solve it by using a constructor